# How to check if webpage are alive with python with multiproccessing

Tags: python, http

I have a list of urls (about 25k) and I am trying to check if they are alive (200 response).  want to do these checks in parallel using the multiprocessing library for Python. I wrote the following (largely based on the Python doc example) but it seems to run pretty slowly. Is there any way I can make this script run faster?

```
    import urllib2
    import time
    import random

    from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, current_process, freeze_support

    class HeadRequest(urllib2.Request):
        def get_method(self):
            return "HEAD"
    #
    # Function run by worker processes
    #

    def worker(input, output):
        for args in iter(input.get, 'STOP'):
            result = alive(args) 
            output.put(result)

    #
    # Functions referenced by tasks
    #

    def alive(x):
        x = x.strip()
        try:
            return x, ":", urllib2.urlopen(HeadRequest(x)).getcode()
        except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
            return x, ":", e.code
        except:
            return x, ": Error"

    #
    #
    #

    def check():
        NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES = 500
        text_file = open("url.txt", "r")
        TASKS1 = text_file.readlines()

        # Create queues
        task_queue = Queue()
        done_queue = Queue()

        # Submit tasks
        for task in TASKS1:
            task_queue.put(task)

        # Start worker processes
        for i in range(NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES):
            Process(target=worker, args=(task_queue, done_queue)).start()

        # Get and print results
        for i in range(len(TASKS1)):
            print done_queue.get()

        # Tell child processes to stop
        for i in range(NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES):
            task_queue.put('STOP')


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        freeze_support()
        check()
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy way:

http://scrapy.org/

Scrapy provides web crawler framework for Python: you can give it a list of URLs to crawl (in your case it doesn't need to follow links) and it will automatically scale to several crawlers within the process/thread limitations you give to it - you don't need to go to the details of multiprocess communications and scaling yourself.

http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/scrapyd.html#topics-scrapyd

The only thing left for your own code is to analyze the results.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to be what I am looking for!

Comment: Somewhat related, do you have any suggestion about how to implement your own parallel processing script? For example instead of checking the status of the web server, could I somehow do a simple ping test?